# what changes in routing were made between Rails 3 and Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Are those changes major or minor? I'm concerned mostyl because gems for translating routing stopped working (rails-translate-routes - problem with helpers generating paths) and i'm looking for some way to repair it

Comment: Let us know when you have solved the issue. I'd like to know how to fix it as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [this](https://github.com/enriclluelles/route_translator) gem and it's doing fine

Answer (score 1):

There are some details about routing changes [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html) Looks like the main changes are the move to the PATCH verb, raising on conflicting named routes, and direct drawing of unicode routes. The first could be significant if you're specifying the PUT verb in your routes or in custom forms in your code. The others are fairly minor for most applications I would guess.